# Foundation 5 topbar - disable JS menu collapse on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

Is it possible to disable the default behaviour of the top bar to collapse on mobile?  I have a left hand menu and right hand menu.  I want to keep the right hand menu exactly the same on all screen sizes and do NOT want it to collapse on a mobile/ tablet.

So the desktop version has a few menu items on the left and on the right it shows three icons, each with a dropdown.  I want the right hand menu to look the exactly the same on a mobile, the left hand menu will collapse as normal.

This is what I want to achieve on a mobile:

[image]

And this JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9d6jh8n/ shows you how close I have got.

I have been trying to figure this out for weeks.  Can anyone help?

original code:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar >
        <ul class="title-area">
            <!-- Title Area -->
            <li class="name">&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <!-- main nav section -->
            <ul class="left">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Links</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#" class="">Dropdown Level 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!--Language, account, currency section-->
            <ul class="right">
                <li class="has-dropdown" id="account">
                    <a href="#" class="top-bar-colour1"><i class="fi-en"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown"><li><a href="#">Languages</a></li></ul> 
                </li>
                <li class="has-dropdown" id="basket">
                    <a href="#" class="top-bar-colour2"><i class="fi-dollar"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown"><li><a href="#">Currency</a></li></ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-dropdown" id="currency">
                    <a href="#" class="top-bar-colour3"><i class="fi-lock medium"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown"><li><a href="#">Login</a></li></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all add following CSS to override the foundation.css:

```
.top-bar-section ul {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    display: inline !important;
}

.row:before, .row:after {
    content: " " !important;
    display: table !important;
}

.top-bar-section ul li {
    float: left !important;
}

.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: inset 5px;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) transparent transparent transparent;
    border-top-style: solid;
    margin-top: -2.5px;
    top: 22.5px;
}

.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a {
    padding-right: 35px !important;
}

.top-bar-section .right li .dropdown {
    left: auto !important;
    right: 0 !important;
}

.top-bar-section .dropdown {
    left: 0 !important;
    top: auto !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    min-width: 100% !important;
}

.top-bar-section li.active:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {
    padding: 0 15px !important;
    line-height: 45px !important;
    color: white !important;
    background: #008cba !important;
}

.top-bar-section .has-dropdown.hover > .dropdown, .top-bar-section .has-dropdown.not-click:hover > .dropdown {
    display: block !important;
    position: static !important;
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    clip: auto !important;
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

Then you have to change your HTML markup.

In your FIDDLE you have a `div.right`. Change it to `ul.right` and put it out of the `ul.left`.

**See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/z9d6jh8n/3/)**

Comment: Hi, I have come across an issue with your solution and that is the "Back" buttons display on the dropdowns on small screens when its not needed.  Any idea why this is?  Many thanks :)

Comment: @LeeTee Can you reconstruate the situation with JSFiddle? I cannot reproduce it... What I mean is, that there is no back button with the Fiddle... Maybe you have an URL to your current working solution...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
nav.show-for-small .right li { float: left; }
nav.show-for-small .small-6 { width: auto; }

.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {
    padding: 0 30px 0 15px;
    line-height: 45px;
}
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
    border: inset 5px;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) transparent transparent transparent;
    border-top-style: solid;
    margin-top: -2.5px;
}
```

Here is Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4gp2hojw/

Comment: What's with the menu hover?